# How to include CoreMl model into the cocoa pod framework?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to create a framework which will be reused across couple of the apps we're currently developing and this framework will include two things:

1. CoreMl model
2. Some amount of code written around this model which will make the work with the model easier

The obstacle I'm currently struggling with is that I can not figure out how to make sure XCode generates the interface class for this model. The thing is, if I'm trying to build the pod itself, I can clearly see that the interface class is being generated. But, if I switch over to the test project I created in order to use this pod, the framework classes start complaining about the use of the unresolved identifier `MyModel`.

Is there anything I'm missing in my podspec or something like that? I'm new to iOS development (was working on Android solely), so pardon me if I accidentally omitted some important parts of my description.

Comment: Does it work if you copy-paste the generated file into a new Swift file and add that to your Xcode project, then turn off the Core ML auto-generation in the project's build settings?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Good question! That was one of my ideas if everything else doesn't work out.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I ended up doing just that and the model seems to work fine. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was to disable the code generation and add the Model class along with ModelInput and ModelOutput which were generated before into the project. After that the test project seems to work just fine with the pod framework containing the model.